# Web Extension - Inject Floating Content into Web Page with Content Script

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a firefox/chrome web extension. When the extension's button is clicked it should inject content into a webpage like this:
[image: Bloomberg_News_Extension]

Here, the Bloomberg News Extension injects something (I can't tell if it is a DIV or an iFrame) into the New York Times page.

The content that is injected has several properties

1) It overlies the current web page

2) When the user scrolls down the web page as a whole, the content follows the scrolling.

In more general form, I am trying to accomplish the following behavior:

[image]

So far, I have the following code in my content script:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = browser.extension.getURL("inject.html");


    iframe.style = "background: #FFFFFF;"
    //These are some test dimensions, in reality, the iFrame should occupy
    //the height of the webpage
    iframe.width = 300;
    iframe.height = 300;
    iframe.align = "right";

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Obviously, my code is far from complete, but I don't really know how to style the iFrame/where I should inject it in order to emulate the behavior presented in the screenshots.

What can I do to accomplish the behavior displayed in the screenshots?

Comment: Inject a div structure and inject an iframe inside the div. This way you can keep separate css for you extension. Inside the iframe you can show extension page.

Comment: @elegant-user Do I apply the styling, such as "align:right" and the width/height values to the DIV?

Comment: Yes. You can inject a css as well

Comment: If you need a sample, I can post it as answer.

Comment: It's ok, I figured out how to do it.

Comment: Great. All the best.